# Hide image in javascript onchange

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to hide image using javascript here's my code. unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
 function showLoader(loaderType) {
        if (loaderType == "AO") {
            document.getElementById("VAO").style.display = '';
        }
        else if (loaderType == "NatureOfBusiness") {
            document.getElementById("ctl00_details_check").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("validateBusiness").style.display = '';
        }
        else if (loaderType == "Button") {
            document.getElementById("loaderButton").style.display = '';
        }
    }
```

aspx code

```
   <asp:TextBox onchange="showLoader('NatureOfBusiness')" ID="txtNatureOfBusiness" Width="200"
   runat="server" CssClass="txt-box" OnTextChanged="txtNatureOfBusiness_TextChanged"
   AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

    <img id='check' runat="server" visible="false" src='../images/check.png' style='height: 20px;' />
    <img id='cross' runat="server" visible="false" src='../images/cross.png' style='height: 17px;' />
    <img id='validateBusiness' src='../images/updating.gif' style="display: none; height: 12px;" />
```

Comment: Remove the Visible="false" since you are trying to hide using a style

Answer (score 0):

You should add `javascript:` to `onchange` method like below.

```
   <asp:TextBox onchange="javascript:showLoader('NatureOfBusiness')" ID="txtNatureOfBusiness" Width="200"
   runat="server" CssClass="txt-box" OnTextChanged="txtNatureOfBusiness_TextChanged"
   AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Is `onchange` fired onblur, isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean that `onchange` is fired on text change but `showLoader` doesn't work?